# Add new property to Vuex store object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have this initial state:

```
state: {
    alertsByQuestionId: {
        // <questionId>: {
        //     <alertId>: false
        // }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on the alert for this question, I need to add alert to the existing state object. So in mutations I'm doing this:

`Vue.set(state.alertsByQuestionId, 22, {1 : false} );`

So it adds one property to the state and I have:

`state.alertsByQuestionId: {22: {1: false}}`

But when I click on another alert, the state is replaced with the second alert, but the first one disappears. So when I do:
`Vue.set(state.alertsByQuestionId, 22, {2 : false} );`

I get:
`state.alertsByQuestionId: {22: {2: false}}`

But what I need is:
`state.alertsByQuestionId: {22: {1:false, 2: false}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was solved using state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the old object with the new one. Instead, you should save a copy of the old one, modify its value and set it back as follows:

```js
var alertsByQuestionId = {
      22: {1:false}
};
let key = Object.keys(alertsByQuestionId)[0];
console.log(alertsByQuestionId);
alertsByQuestionId[key][2] = false;
console.log(alertsByQuestionId);
```